# will the nested try exception be caught by outer catch block

Tags: java, exception

I have something like this

```
try{   
  try{ . .a method call throwing a exception..} 
  finally { ...} 
} catch()...
```

The type of exception thrown by method call and outer catch(type parameter) is same.

Will the nested try exception be caught by outer catch block?

Comment: uncaught exceptions bubble up until they hit a matching catch, or hit the top level scope and cause the entire app to fail.

Comment: @MarcB Not necessarily. If the inner `finally` block completes abruptly, its reason for completion is what will bubble up, not the original exception.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The relevant rules are in the Java Language Specification, [14.20.2. Execution of try-finally and try-catch-finally](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.2)

The result of an exception `V` in the inner `try` block will depend on how the `finally` block completes. If it completes normally, the `try-finally` will complete abruptly due to V. If the `finally` block completes abruptly for some reason `R` then the `try-finally` completes abruptly due to `R`, and `V` is discarded.

Here is a program demonstrating this:

```
public class Test {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      try {
        throw new Exception("First exception");
      } finally {
        System.out.println("Normal completion finally block");
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("In first outer catch, catching " + e);
    }
    try {
      try {
        throw new Exception("Second exception");
      } finally {
        System.out.println("finally block with exception");
        throw new Exception("Third exception");
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("In second outer catch, catching " + e);
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

```
Normal completion finally block
In first outer catch, catching java.lang.Exception: First exception
finally block with exception
In second outer catch, catching java.lang.Exception: Third exception
```

The second outer catch did not see "Second exception" because of the abrupt completion of the second `finally` block.

Try to minimize the risk of abrupt completion of the `finally` block. Handle any exceptions inside it, so that it will complete normally, unless they are going to be fatal to the program as a whole.